# Securely transferring files to new computer

Tags: hard-drive, backup, virus, anti-virus

I currently have a really old computer with tons of viruses on it and I have bought a new one recently to replace it. The problem is I still have some files on my old computer that I need but I'm afraid that if I copy them regularly they will infect my new computer.

My question is, are there software that can securely transfer those files without any viruses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a computer has been infected you can never be *sure* that all the viruses are gone, however, if you follow the below steps, you will have the next best thing.

1. Move the files you desire to a removable HDD or flash drive.
2. Go to your new computer and boot it to a [Live CD with antivirus](http://livecdlist.com/purpose/windows-antivirus)

   1. Make sure your computer is booted to the AV disk before you plug in the removable drive with the questionable content.
   2. I recommend Avira, Kaspersky or Avast! from that list.
3. Scan your media using the live CD. Perform any fixes as needed.
4. Copy your scanned files to your main HDD.
5. Enjoy your recovered files.

Comment: This I think is the most doable thing at all.